# Bash: spawn a process with a new PGID

Tags: linux, bash, unix

In BASH, how can you spawn a BASH process from another BASH process with a different PGID?

So far I'm aware of using only `setsid` (creates a new session ID, and PGID as result) to do that, but I am curious to see if there are any ways to spawn a process with a new PGID while RETAINING session ID.

Answer (score 1):

This does it for me with Debian:

```
exo-open --launch TerminalEmulator
```